# How to change Raspbian default apt-get mirror?

Tags: apt, raspbian

The thing is the mirror that was configured on installation is causing checksum mismatch in all packages.

I read everywhere that in order to change de mirror `apt-get` uses for download I have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/source.list.d/raspi.list`.

The problem is both these files already have a different mirror than the one `apt-get install` is actually using.

They have the `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` mirror. But when I run `apt-get install` it goes to a different one.

So, if not from this files. Where can `apt-get` be taking the mirror URL from?

Comment: Now i think that the mirror is someway dynamic. It usually goes to one in uruguay, which is the one that causes troubles. But yesterday afternoon it went to brazil and it worked fine! then, at night it return to uruguay and its checksum issues.

Answer (score 1):

I finally have it working. I just had to replace the url in the `sources.list` file, even though that URL wasn't the one where it was downloading the packages from. It seems like `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` was doing some kind of dynamic assignment based on my location.

Comment: This was pretty much the answer I was going to post, but didn’t have time to double-check my theory. Good work debugging!